# Подскажите где ошибка?

Tags: php, html

Не пойму, хочу посмотреть значение переменных после отправки формы. обработчик та же страница

```
echo  $description, $class, $audio,  $answer, $tonality ;
```

но всё безуспешно, под конец совсем запутался. Помогите.

```
<form action="add_material.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform"></form>
<!-- кусок таблицы -->
<tr>
              <td><input type="textarea" name="description" form="myform"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="class" form="myform"></td>
              <td>
                  Аудио (строго mp3)<br>  
              <input name="userfile[]" type="file" form="myform"><br><br>
                  Ответ (строго png)<br>
              <input name="userfile[]" type="file" form="myform"><br>
              </td>
              <td><select required size = "1" name = "tonality" form="myform">
                    <option disabled>Тональность</option>
                    <option value = "C-dur_nastroi.mp3">C-Dur</option>
                    <option value = "d-moll_nastroi.mp3">d-moll</option>
                  </select></td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="add"  form="myform"/> </td>
            </tr>
             <?php  

                if ( isset( $_POST['description'] ) and isset( $_POST['class'] ) and isset( $_POST['userfile[0]'] ) and isset( $_POST['userfile[1]'] ) and isset( $_POST['tonality'] )) {
                $description = $_POST['description'];  
                $class = $_POST['class'];
                $audio = $_POST['userfile[0]'];
                $answer = $_POST['userfile[1]'];
                $tonality = $_POST['tonality'];
                echo  $description, $class, $audio,  $answer, $tonality ;    
                }
?>
```

Comment: Проверьте содержимое $_POST через var_dump, будет более понятно что приходит на страницу а что нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что файлы прилетают в глобальный массив [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), а не в `$_POST`

При этом будет даже не так

```
$_FILES['userfile[0]']
```

а вот так

```
$_FILES['userfile']
```

Если конкретно то распечатка массива `$_FILES['userfile']` будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => musicName1.mp3
                    [1] => musicName2.mp3
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => audio/mp3
                    [1] => audio/mp3
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => W:\userdata\temp\phpC521.tmp
                    [1] => W:\userdata\temp\phpC63B.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14539039
                    [1] => 10321791
                )    
        )    
)
```

Отсюда и не отрабатывают ваши условия и поэтому ничего не печатает.

На будущее: подучите основы и еще выучите такие хорошие функции как [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php) и [print_r](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php) для того, чтобы смотреть что где пришло

Answer (score 0):

Тег формы, должен закрываться после окончания всех инпутов как минимум =)

Comment: Я же указываю каждому инпуту form="myform"
Разве этого не достаточно?

Comment: _userfile[0]_ - ты не можешь использовать данный элемент массива в проверке и выводе, так как при отправке форме из данных полей ввода, формируется массив _$_FILES_ вот его и проверяй.

Comment: Вот попробуй в тегах **<?php ?>**, только не под условием написать **var_dump($_FILES);**